# Kotlin native MPP stability warning

Tags: kotlin, gradle, kotlin-native

In a Kotlin/native project, `gradlew build` successfully builds the project, but emits the warning:

> Kotlin Multiplatform Projects are an Alpha feature. See:
> https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/evolution/components-stability.html.
> To hide this message, add 'kotlin.mpp.stability.nowarn=true' to the
> Gradle properties.

So, I tried adding `kotlin.mpp.stability.nowarn=true` to `settings.gradle.kts`. This didn't work, I get the error:

```
Script compilation errors:
  Line 2: kotlin.mpp.stability.nowarn = true
                 ^ Unresolved reference: mpp
  Line 2: kotlin.mpp.stability.nowarn = true
                               ^ Variable expected
2 errors
```

I tried renaming `settings.gradle.kts` to `settings.gradle` to use Groovy syntax, but then I get the error:

```
A problem occurred evaluating settings 'kangaroo-kotlin'.
> Could not get unknown property 'kotlin' for settings 'kangaroo-kotlin' of type org.gradle.initialization.DefaultSettings.
```

How to correctly set the flag to get rid of the warning?

Answer (score 2):

Add the flag to a file named `gradle.properties`, which should be located in the same directory as `settings.gradle.kts`

```
── my-project/
    ├── gradle/
    ├── src/
    ├── build.gradle.kts
    ├── settings.gradle.kts
    └── gradle.properties
```

```
# contents of gradle.properties


kotlin.mpp.stability.nowarn=true
```